# Shared spaces between two monitors, but cycle both monitors at the same time

Tags: mac, spaces

The best I can explain is like so:

```
Spaces: 1 2 3 4 5
Monitors: [ ] [ ]
```

Say I start with spaces 1 and 2 on screen with 3,4,5 off-screen:

```
[1] [2] 3 4 5
```

Then I swipe right. I'd like to have something like this:

```
1 [2] [3] 4 5
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Two days & no-one has picked up on this yet… I don't think it's possible. You can shift monitors in pairs if you disable the 'Displays have separate Spaces' pref, but shuffling them in your desired fashion like a conveyor-belt isn't possible in a single step. You'd have to shift each individually [possibly also having to avoid 'two-of-a-kind' simultaneously.]